# Need sqlite 3 stdcall library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, mfc

In VS2010 I have a MFC vc++ application which depends upon 3 dlls with calling type as _STDCALL. Now I have to use SQLite3 database with the application as a library .

But unfortunately I cannot build a static library or dll with STDCALL. It gives me compilation error(information is followed) while doing so.

```
> Compilation error

cannot convert symbol qsort(int *...)stdcall to qsort(int *...)cdecl..
in the stdlib.h of sqlite package
```

However it compiles perfectly with CDECL convention.

Can you please tell me steps to build with STDCALL ?
Or how to overcome this problem?

Comment: *"It gives me compilation error"* ..... and is the error message a secret?

Comment: @RogerRowland Something like cannot convert symbol qsort(int *...)stdcall to qsort(int *...)cdecl.. in the stdlib.h of sqlite package.

Answer (score 0):

I googled for this and got an advise that SQLite3 cannot be compiled with STDLIB standards.

So i rebuilt ,all my other dependent  projects with CDECL

Sorry for late reply.

Thanks,

Selva